# Calculating distance between two points is very Slow

Tags: mysql

I'm storing a map of X,Y coordinates inside POINT() rows, in 'coordinates' table.

Currently it's a 1000x1000 grid map so there is 1 MILLION rows

if i want to select all neighbouring coordinates for selected point (let's assume it's 130, 130) i'm firing this query:

```
SET @x = 130;
SET @y = 130;

SELECT astext(PointFromWKB(coordinates)) AS coords, 
ROUND(GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(coordinates))),
      GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(POINT(@x, @y)))))))) AS distance 
FROM coordinates 
ORDER BY distance
```

But it's VERY slow - it takes approx ~2,50 seconds to process this query, if i remove ORDER BY statement, it's pretty much instant.

How i can speed it up?

I created SPATIAL index for coords column but i have no idea how to use it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

you can separate the query and the order by as follows

```js
SET @x = 130;
SET @y = 130;

select * from (
SELECT astext(PointFromWKB(coordinates)) AS coords, 
ROUND(GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(coordinates))),
      GeomFromText(astext(PointFromWKB(POINT(@x, @y)))))))) AS distance 
FROM coordinates ) as t  
ORDER BY distance;
```

this will run your query quickly, and then order the result set which is also a quick operation.

Comment: Thanks, but it took even more time with this query (3.522 seconds).  :) I guess i should select only a range of coordinates with WHERE clause and SPATIAL index but i have no idea how to get around it.